# Set an array of elements not in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of numbers

```
const numbers = [12,37,5,42,8,3];
```

And i want to set an array of even numbers from my initial array

```
const even = numbers.filter((number) => {return number % 2==0; });
```

I new a method to get the odd numbers by extracting the even numbers out of the initial array.

or even better, what's the optimal way to the two array with less computation/iterations?

Comment: Instead of `number % 2==0`, try `number & 1` for odd or `!(number & 1)` for even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one iteration:

```
const {even, odd} = numbers.reduce((a, b) => (a[b % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'].push(b), a) , {even: [], odd: []});
```

Comment: this is simply awesome